# Adding images to a DOCX

Tags: docx4j

I have a template DOCX file that I am working with. The template file contains two placeholders for images (a logo and a barcode image). How can I replace these images using BufferedImage or just getting an image from a URL? There seem to not be many resources on this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work using bookmarks. Apparently I didn't dig deeper before posting the question. The code is below. Although I did not find the methods to control the width and height of the image, which is important, the code below does answer my question.

```
public void addLogoAndBarCode(WordprocessingMLPackage pack, String agencyID)
  {
      MainDocumentPart documentPart = pack.getMainDocumentPart();
      Document wmlDoc = (Document) documentPart.getJaxbElement();
      Body body = wmlDoc.getBody();
      List<Object> paragraphs = body.getContent();
      RangeFinder rt = new RangeFinder("CTBookmark", "CTMarkupRange");
      new TraversalUtil(paragraphs, rt);
      for(CTBookmark bm:rt.getStarts())
      {
         if(bm.getName().equals("agencyLogo"))
         {
             logger.info("i found bookmark");
             try
             {
               InputStream is = new FileInputStream(agencyLogoPath+agencyID+".jpg");
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(pack, bytes);
                Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline(null, null, 0,1, false, 800);
                P p = (P)(bm.getParent());
                ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
                R run = factory.createR();
                Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
                drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
                run.getContent().add(drawing);
                p.getContent().add(run);

             }
             catch(Exception er)
             {
                 er.printStackTrace();
             }
         } 
      }
  }
```

Comment: If you have a reference to the image part, you can replace the image contents in the part.  Doing this retains the existing properties (height, width)  specified in the existing anchor.  I expect the createImageInline approach in the answer above will leave your placeholder images present in the docx zip file, even though they are not visible?